# Parse nested xml simplexml_load_string/ simple xml object using looping or direct access

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am newbie to PHP. I have following XML file. I want to parse **component**. As you can see component tag is repeated here. I am using `simplexml_load_string` to get the response from the HTTP request. This XML schema is repeated here (`<order>` `</order>`) is repeated here. I want to parse all the using looping or direct access.

```
<Order>
    <AmazonOrderID>406-6143419-7223518</AmazonOrderID>
    <MerchantOrderID>406-6143419-7223518</MerchantOrderID>
    <ShipmentID>DDNSkvgJN</ShipmentID>
    <MarketplaceName>Amazon.in</MarketplaceName>
    <Fulfillment>
        <MerchantFulfillmentID>AFN</MerchantFulfillmentID>
        <PostedDate>2017-07-22T08:31:18+00:00</PostedDate>
        <Item>
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>31251963544243</AmazonOrderItemCode>
            <SKU>DZ-HA0T-A5GQ</SKU>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <ItemPrice>
                <Component>
                    <Type>Principal</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">780.47</Amount>
                </Component>
                <Component>
                    <Type>Shipping</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">13.02</Amount>
                </Component>
                <Component>
                    <Type>Tax</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">174.78</Amount>
                </Component>
            </ItemPrice>
            <ItemFees>
                <Fee>
                    <Type>FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">-10.00</Amount>
                </Fee>
                <Fee>
                    <Type>FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFeeTax</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">-1.80</Amount>
                </Fee>
                <Fee>
                    <Type>FBAWeightBasedFee</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">-43.00</Amount>
                </Fee>
                <Fee>
                    <Type>FBAWeightBasedFeeTax</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">-7.74</Amount>
                </Fee>
                <Fee>
                    <Type>Commission</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">-135.83</Amount>
                </Fee>
                <Fee>
                    <Type>CommissionTax</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">-24.45</Amount>
                </Fee>
                <Fee>
                    <Type>FixedClosingFee</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">-20.00</Amount>
                </Fee>
                <Fee>
                    <Type>FixedClosingFeeTax</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">-3.60</Amount>
                </Fee>
            </ItemFees>
            <Promotion>
                <MerchantPromotionID>DCMS-3f4089f9-060b2c1e</MerchantPromotionID>
                <Type>Principal</Type>
                <Amount currency="INR">-156.25</Amount>
            </Promotion>
            <Promotion>
                <MerchantPromotionID>IN Core Free Shipping 2015/04/08 23-48-5-108</MerchantPromotionID>
                <Type>Shipping</Type>
                <Amount currency="INR">-13.02</Amount>
            </Promotion>
        </Item>
    </Fulfillment>
</Order>
```

So far I've tried this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlDoc); 
foreach($xml->children() as $node) { 
  echo $node->AmazonOrderID . ", ";
  echo $node->ShipmentID . ", "; 
  echo $node->SKU . ", "; 
  echo $node->Component . "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We will not write the code for you.

Comment: The PHP manual has a [page of simple examples](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) which should show you enough to parse a simple XML document like this.

Answer (score 1):

I've put the data into a file, but this is a simple change to the load bit (I use _file, not _string) But the rest of the code should show you how you can access the hierarchy of the data...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo $xml->AmazonOrderID . ", ";
echo $xml->ShipmentID . ", ";
echo $xml->SKU . ", ";
foreach($xml->Fulfillment->Item as $item) {
    foreach ( $item->ItemPrice->Component as $component )   {
        echo "Type:".$component->Type." Amount:".$component->Amount.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Which gives you...

```
406-6143419-7223518, DDNSkvgJN, , Type:Principal Amount:780.47
Type:Shipping Amount:13.02
Type:Tax Amount:174.78
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access Component elements easily with xpath method.

```
$components = $xml->xpath('Fulfillment/Item/ItemPrice/Component');
print_r($components);
```

That gives you this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Type] => Principal
            [Amount] => 780.47
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Type] => Shipping
            [Amount] => 13.02
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Type] => Tax
            [Amount] => 174.78
        )

)
```

Comment: You can see it working here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/93c16986fc85a03fc20804a2f30ae4ae570ac461 They don't allow `simplexml_load_string` so I used `new SimpleXMLElement`.